# How to access superclass properties here

Tags: python

I have moved `NEW_MESSAGE_ON_PROJECT` and `NEW_MESSAGE_ON_PROPOSAL` to `BaseNotification`, the superclass.

```
class CustomerNotification(BaseNotification):
    NEW_PROPOSAL = 1000
    # NEW_MESSAGE_ON_PROJECT = 1001
    # NEW_MESSAGE_ON_PROPOSAL = 1002
    CHOICES = ((NEW_PROPOSAL, "New Prpposal"),
               (NEW_MESSAGE_ON_PROJECT, "New Message on Project"),
               (NEW_MESSAGE_ON_PROPOSAL,"New Message on Proposal"))
```

When I set CHOICES, I get

```
NameError: name 'NEW_MESSAGE_ON_PROJECT' is not defined
```

I dont get `self` context here. So whats the solution?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to explicitly use the name of the base class:

```
class CustomerNotification(BaseNotification):
    NEW_PROPOSAL = 1000
    # NEW_MESSAGE_ON_PROJECT = 1001
    # NEW_MESSAGE_ON_PROPOSAL = 1002
    CHOICES = ((NEW_PROPOSAL, "New Prpposal"),
               (BaseNotification.NEW_MESSAGE_ON_PROJECT, 
                "New Message on Project"),
               (BaseNotification.NEW_MESSAGE_ON_PROPOSAL,
                "New Message on Proposal"))
```

The reason for this is that you get a clean namespace when starting a class definition, similar (but certainly not equal) to the namespace you get when you start a function.

This namespace does not include anything from the base class. Accessing base class members is handled when accessing members of the finished class (or their objects, for that matter).

Comment: Could you elaborate on last paragraph? Are base class members available only when you instantiate an object?

Comment: No, you can also access base class members using the class – but only after the class declaration is finished. Like, after the declaration ``CustomerNotification.NEW_MESSAGE_ON_PROJECT`` works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to reference `BaseNotification.NEW_PROPOSAL` directly.